# To get verification token from Email using Xcuitest

Tags: xcuitest

We are generating a verification password which is sent the user.we need to enter that password in the app to proceed to the next step
is there any way i can capture the password in the email.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

1. (Slow) You can interact with Apple's Mail app using `XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "")` function and get the required code from the email body.
2. (Fast) You can send requests from code to the email server to get the new emails.
3. (Reliable) You can ask your backend team to use predetermined code (e.g. `123456`) for the emails from a specific test domain.